# looping in jquery alert content

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to add a looping inside the content of jquery alert ? i want to display it in my table.

```
  success: function (result) {
   var resultData = JSON.parse(result.data);
         if (resultData.length > 0) {
    $.alert({
      title: 'You Have Memo Notification',
      content: '<table class="table table-sm table-condensed table-hovered table-bordered mt-2">' +
             '<thead class="table-primary"><tr><td>Memo</td></thead>' +
             '<tbody>'    +                          
             '<tr><td> ' + resultData[i].MemoToFileRemarks + '  </td></tr>' +                             
             '</tbody></table>'
            });                
                  }
        }
```

//I want to add this inside my content of jquery alert

```
for (i = 0; i < resultData.length; i++) {

                       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider constructing your results *prior* to issuing the alert to avoid the overhead performing a separate alert for each individual result:

```
success: function (result) {
    var resultData = JSON.parse(result.data),
        resultContent = '';

    // If you have results, then issue an alert
    if (resultData.length > 0) {
        // Build your results
        for (i = 0; i < resultData.length; i++) {
            resultContent += '<tr><td>' + resultData[i].MemoToFileRemarks + '</td></tr>'; 
        }

        // Issue your alert
        $.alert({
            title: 'You Have Memo Notification',
            content: 
              '<table class="table table-sm table-condensed table-hovered table-bordered mt-2">' +
                '<thead class="table-primary"><tr><td>Memo</td></thead>' +
                '<tbody>' +                          
                    resultContent +                        
                '</tbody>' +
              '</table>'
        });                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $.alert({
        title: 'You Have Memo Notification',
        content: 
          '<table class="table table-sm table-condensed table-hovered table-bordered mt-2">' +
            '<thead class="table-primary"><tr><td>Memo</td></thead>' +
            '<tbody>' +  
               for (let item of resultData) {
                 '<tr><td>' + item.MemoToFileRemarks + '</td></tr>'; 
                }                        
                +                        
            '</tbody>' +
          '</table>'
    });
```